Is Hermiticity dependent on the choice of inner product?
We have the two standard definitions of Hermiticity:

$A_{ij} = \overline{A_{ji}}$ (i.e. $A = \overline{A^T}$), which references the basis
$\langle A x, y\rangle = \langle x, Ay\rangle$ (i.e. $A = A^\dagger$), which references the IP

The correctness of the latter definition demonstrates that Hermiticity is actually basis-independent. Unfortunately, I'm unable to prove or find a counterexample that Hermiticity is actually IP-independent too.
Thus, the question: is Hermiticity IP-independent? If so, why? If not, what's a counterexample?
